# Is Dr. Strange a Member of the Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

After watching Dr. Strange and seeing his role in Avengers: Infinity War, I've come to a question: Is Dr. Strange a member of the Avengers, or is he more a "I'm here when you need me" player?

Kind of like Batman in the DC Universe. He doesn't necessarily do the whole "I'm part of the team!!!" thing, and is simply available when needed (and sometimes when not, but has something to contribute). His goal is more to keep his home of Gotham City safe, and if that means joining the JL every once in a while to ensure outside forces don't become a threat, then so be it (sure Wayne Enterprises may have funded the JL facilities (animated series), but for the sake of the movies I digress).

Strange's main role/purpose is to protect the New York sanctum(and perhaps the whole realm, since the other sanctums were destroyed?) to the multiverse and protect mankind. Thus, he can't just go to work at the Avengers Facility, he has his own lair to watch over and protect.

Comment: How do you define "a full-blown Avenger"?

Comment: Batman is not only a full-blown member of the Justice League, he's one of the founding members, in every variation of it that I can think of. It's true he's more of a rogue element than some of the others, but he can and will speak for them, 
and make snap decisions for them.

Comment: Mostly, Batman's just more busy than the others.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Is Dr. Strange a Full-Blown Avenger?

### Dr. Strange is exclusively a member of the Masters of the Mystic Arts.

From the *Dr. Strange* film, just after Strange is caught using the Eye of Agamotto for the first time:

> WONG: You were born for the Mystic Arts.
>
> STRANGE: And yet my hands still shake.
>
> MORDO: For now, yes.
>
> STRANGE: Not forever?
>
> MORDO: We're not prophets.
>
> STRANGE: **When do you start telling me what we are?**
>
> WONG: **While heroes like the Avengers protect the world from physical dangers, we sorcerers safeguard it against more mystical threats.** The Ancient One is the latest in a long line of Sorcerers Supreme.

#### The fact that the *Avengers* and the *Masters of the Mystic Arts* are fighting together in *Infinity War* is simply a result of Thanos being from outer space and having mystical powers, and because he's coming to Earth.

Since there's both "physical" and "mystical" aspects to the fight that Thanos brings, this necessitates the two organizations working together.

And, per the events of *Avengers: Infinity War*, this is one of the reasons why Heimdall sent Bruce Banner to the Masters of the Mystic Arts -- because their job is to specifically combat mystical enemies from outer space.

***So, all in all, Dr. Strange isn't a member of the Avengers any more than Wong is.***

Comment: "Thanos ... having mystical powers". Do you have a source for that? It's more likely that Dr Strange protects the Time stone, which Thanos wants. Note that Wong didn't help fight after Strange left Earth.

Comment: @jaxad0127 Thanos's abilities are covered [in another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88706/does-thanos-have-any-inherent-superpowers-without-the-infinity-stones) that might interest you.

Comment: I don't think the "Masters of the Mystic Arts" is a proper name of some group. Do you have a source for that? There's also nothing about Dr Strange or the sorcerers creed that says they fight "mystical beings from outer space" Rather, I seem to recall them specifically mentioning they guard Earth from foes from other *dimensions*. Also what is your source that Heimdall intentionally sent Hulk to the New York headquarters via the bifrost? There's no indication in the movie that he sent him anywhere more specific than "Earth". This answer seems to make a *lot* of assumptions

Comment: *"Also what is your source that Heimdall intentionally sent Hulk to the New York headquarters via the bifrost? There's no indication in the movie that he sent him anywhere more specific than "Earth". "* -- Seriously? You really think that Heimdall didn't intentionally send Banner to Strange? That, out of all the locations and buildings in the entire world, it's purely coincidental that Banner was shot to the exact same location/place as Strange? I'm sure..

Comment: @maxathousand That covers various comic versions and doesn't say anything about mystic abilities anyways.

Comment: @jaxad0127 that answer cites Marvel as a direct source, so I’m not sure what “various versions” you mean. Also, it details several supernatural abilities, so maybe your definition of “mystical” differs from mine. Finally, I did say that answer only *might* interest you...

Comment: @jaxad0127 Another line of reasoning that would support Thanos having mystical powers: the Time Stone is heavily used in the practice of Mystic Arts. It was, in fact, even used by the first Sorcerer Supreme of the Mystic Arts - Agamotto. So then, it may be safe to say that the Time Stone has mystical powers/capabilities, given that it's used in the practice of Mystic Arts. And then, additionally -- since the other Infinity Stones that are in Thanos's possession come from the very same place that the Time Stone does, then, there's no reason to distinguish them as something other than Mystic.

Comment: @jaxad0127 But really, unless you're splitting hairs, then, what else would you call it -- the ability to turn weapons into bubbles, people into ribbons, minds into madness, and trillions into ashes -- other than *mystical*?

Comment: Thanos is a physical danger from this dimension/universe. He has his hands on some pretty big macguffins and a tech created by dwarves that lets him use it - just science really. In the context of the MCU, "mystical" represents more extra-dimensional. The Sorceror Supreme did nothing (that we know of) to combat Malekith when he literally threated to UNMAKE REALITY, because their focus was on greater threats from other dimensions.

Comment: Really tho, there's just a lot of random assumption going on here. There's no actual indication that Heimdall specifically sent Bruce Banner to Dr. Strange, or why, or for that matter why Heimdall sent Bruce at all. The whole "Masters of the Mystic Arts" job description as combating mystical enemies from outer space is ... unsupported and inaccurate. And the fact that he's a member of another org doesn't by itself mean that he's not an Avenger - it's perfectly possible to be a part of multiple orgs, there's just actual evidence that Dr Stephen Strange is not (would improve this answer).

Answer (score 15):

As far as the MCU is concerned, Dr. Stephen Strange is not a member of the Avengers in any way.

- As of the end of Civil War, only signatories to the Sokovia Accords are official members of the Avengers, the others "retire permanently", and are considered criminals. I'm going to count this as the definition of **full-blown Avenger** since it's the most applicable definition in-universe.
- He was never a member of the Avengers prior to the Accords either.
- No one on the Avengers team* even knows of the existence of Sorcerors prior to Infinity War. It's only in Infinity War that they begin finding out that there are wizards now.

Whether he could at some point become a member of the Avengers in the future is an entirely different story. Hypothetically, the Avengers' mission/purpose could be expanded to multi-dimensional threats, and/or Strange could operate in coordination with the Avengers to combat those threats - after all, even Sorcerors must eat, and have money to pay for Tuna Melts and Metaphysical Ham on Ryes. Not to mention even multi-dimensional beings can involve physical threats like minions.

*Technically, Thor found out that "*Earth has wizards now*" in Thor: Ragnarok, but he isn't an official Avengers member either, and hasn't communicated with the Avengers in a while.

Answer (score 6):

No, he's not an official Avengers team member.  Tony Stark had never even met the man (in the MCU anyway) prior to Infinity War, when he appeared out of a sling-ring portal to ask for Tony's help, bringing Bruce Banner along with him.

Throughout the movie, Dr Strange also states many times that he's not under Tony's command, will sacrifice Tony and Peter to protect the Time Stone and so on.  He doesn't want to be considered part of the Avengers "team", as his primary concern is the protection of the Time Stone.

Wong explained to Strange in the Dr Strange movie that while people like the Avengers protect the world from physical dangers, it's the job of the Sorcerers to protect the world from more mystical threats.

It's unlikely that Dr Strange will join the Avengers any time soon, as you have pointed out - he has his own priorities in terms of global protection.

Comment: *"Wong explained to Strange in the Dr Strange movie that while people like the Avengers protect the world from physical dangers"* Wasn't that Mordo?

Comment: I'd thought it was the Ancient One to be honest, but I checked IMDB and that said it was Wong :)

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211837/quotes?item=qt3084718

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, let's gather some supporting information first.

**Dr. Stephen Strange** - Let's discuss about his brief background first, he is a Doctor, a Neurosurgeon, an ordinary man who met with his terrible fate after a car accident which brought his hands into a serious trauma resulting to the loss of the stability of his grip and a difficulty to control them. He was unable to perform any surgeries with precision, therefore began losing his confidence, pride and name. He researched about the people who has the same situation as him but were healed mysteriously, he came up with a person who lost the control of his legs but then is healed and became normal again. Dr. Strange searches to this person and asked how did he become normal again, that is where Dr. Strange was lead up into Nepal to the temple where sorcerers together with their trainer "The Ancient One" train to be powerful enough to prepare for an invasion of Dormammu, a powerful celestial demon who will be summoned by his followers (an ex-sorcerer who have lost their ways) that gained power from the dark dimension.
The Ancient one shows Dr. Strange his inner-self and he can have powers by focusing his mind. After several days of training, Dr. Strange knew that the power he possess is limitless, that he can do much more than he has done. He researched into the library and finds an astonishing discovery, the Eye of Agamotto (the Infinity stone of Time), a necklace that can control time. ** FORWARD ** He found out that the Ancient One also draws power from the dark dimension for the greater good, now that The Ancient One is killed by one of Dormammu's followers, he knew that not all people who uses bad things are for bad things to. After the coming of Dormammu, he uses the Time Stone to rewind everything back the way they were before, but then he realized that Dormammu will still come even though he will rewind everything back, so he stopped the time and trapped Dormammu into an endless loop where Dr. Strange rewinds again and again after being executed by Dormammu, as an agreement, Dr. Strange bargains with Dormammu to set him free from the endless time loop if he will go back from where he came from and never visit Earth again. Dr. Strange succeeded with the trade and saves the planet.

**

> So - Will now Dr. Strange be a part of Avengers?

**

**Answer:** Most likely no... well, perhaps not yet.

He did not know that there is a past war between villains and the original Avengers anyway, it so happened that Hulk (Bruce Banner) dropped from space and then delivers the message about Thanos' wrath. He is just an ordinary Doctor seeking for solutions about his hands, if it wasn't for Bruce, he won't know about the past and ongoing war of the Avengers. Since he volunteered to join with Stark to fight for the Earth's freedom then we can call him an Avenger now. But...again, he is not officially an Avenger. We need a confirmation from the Avengers team if he will become a part of it. 
(**PLOT TWIST**)[May Contain Spoilers] However, during the Infinity War movie, he traveled into time to for-see the chances of Thanos being defeated, from over 14 Million Chances, Thanos will be defeated by only 1 chance. So the Dr. Strange's decision giving Thanos the Time Stone is the chance that he has seen to be the only way that could  bring Thanos down. But then after Thanos snapped his fingers, half of living creatures in the universe will all be gone, that includes Dr. Strange, we do not know what will happen next but those who were left behind are the original Avengers.

I think that will answer your question now.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Would you mind breaking this up into paragraphs so it's a bit easier to read? At the moment, I'm not sure how much of this is actually relevant to the question.