# Thor, God of Thunder, is easily imprisoned by Ebony Maw in Infinity War. Why is this?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thor-ragnarok

In the final scenes of *Thor: Ragnarok*, exactly one movie prior, we see Thor fully realize his God of Thunder might against Hela.  It's not quite enough (huh?) and Surtur is who does in Hela (at least we are led to believe that...)

Opening scene of *Infinity War*, we see Thor bested by Thanos and Children of Thanos members. Ebony Maw easily subdues him with metal from a ship that is not of Asgard (ship comes from Grandmaster's collection on Sakaar).

Is Thor's powers only tied to Asgard's existence?  He makes one attempt on Thanos after Hulk fails... without using God of Thunder powers.

We know Thor's power isn't necessarily tied to wielding a Nidavilir forged weapon like Mjolnir, but I'm still wondering how Thor, God of Thunder, is completely bested by Thanos, granted with an Infinity Stone.

Comment: Seems to me you've answered your own question - *"I'm still wondering how Thor, God of Thunder, is completely bested by Thanos, **granted with an Infinity Stone**"*

Comment: Also, Thanos was able to defeat the Hulk without even trying hard....

Comment: See - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92247/how-was-thanos-able-to-defeat-hulk-in-infinity-war-without-using-any-stone

Comment: Could he even summon lightning on a spaceship? Weather phenomena usually require a planet with significant atmosphere.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few things that could explain this:

1. Thor is able to use his powers against Hela, but they are still new to him and he is not use to wielding them without a "focus" like his hammer. While he is incredibly powerful, he struggles to use his powers effectively.
2. Thanos is no slouch. He's referred to as the strongest being in the universe" multiple times, and with good reason. Thanos and company have already breached the ship and slaughtered quite a few Asgardian warriors (notice the bodies strewn around in the opening scene).
3. Heimdall is similarly incapacitated, despite being a mighty warrior as well.
4. Ebony Maw binds Thor *after* he takes a beating from Thanos

Comment: Adding something here, we should also consider mind state of Thor at the time. he lost his people, and soon to be see something bad happen to his brother, one of his best friends, Heimdall was killed etc... Considering the fact, that all the powers are new to him, without the hammer, Thor wouldn't have much mentaly strong at that time...

Answer (score 0):

Ebony Maw is no doubt the best one in the  MCU black order (no supergiant). Moreover, Ebony Maw can control objects as per his will.

In the entire run of *Avengers: Infinity War*, notice how he always uses almost no strength to move even very large metal equipment etc. (Dr.Strange's rescue scene) which shows very little of his potential used in the movie.

His power is what makes him the right-hand of the Mad-Titan and one of the reason he bows to him is that because Thanos is the one there is! (Rocket's quote), and he has the might and nobility to wield all stones together, where a majority of beings can't even survive holding just one.

Coming back to your question, Ebony mow can lift and throw heavy things at someone with same ease, whether its a human or Mighty Thor on the other side.
In the movie, he uses the metal to bind thor, Thor was trapped due to the intensity and quantity of the metal as well, moreover, he was there in the presence of the black order, the trauma he just went through seeing his people slaughtered as well and Thanos himself who just tossed him and Hulk without a sweat.