# What makes Thanos the most powerful being in the universe?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, when Ronan got stone of infinity on Knowhere and decided to not give the stone to Thanos, Korath told him that Thanos is the most powerful being in the universe. Why is he so powerful? His only abilities so far I can see are achieved using the stones in Avengers. His only visible power is strength, but without stones he would not have chance even against most Avengers in 1v1 fight.

I didn't read any Marvel comics, I've just seen the films, so are there any abilities he doesn't use in the films? Or why is he considered the most powerful being if he seems so weak without the stones (compared to Avengers, for example)?

Comment: because he has the *ability* to wield all the stones.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88706/does-thanos-have-any-inherent-superpowers-without-the-infinity-stones Does Thanos have any inherent superpowers without the Infinity Stones

Comment: I don't understand your claim that "he would not have chance even against most Avengers", when the very first scene in Infinity War shows him easily defeating the Hulk without using any stones.

Comment: See [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96277/how-did-thanos-defeat-thor-in-the-beginning-of-infinity-war), he had already power stone at the time. Also if you think about abilities of most avengers, Thanos would not be able to even get close to the eg. Scarlet witch and so use his power.

Comment: @FilipKočica If you look at the link you posted or remember the film, Thanos beat Hulk without using either of his infinity stones (see this link: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92250/67819).

Comment: While not necessarily a duplicate, this question already has an answer here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92247/how-was-thanos-able-to-defeat-hulk-in-infinity-war-without-using-any-stone/92250#92250

Comment: Well, Endgame has shown he's anything, but weak, without the Stones, even without additional abilities from comics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## He's an Eternal of Titan.

> Even without the Infinity Gauntlet or THOTU Thanos is still very powerful.
>
> Thanos is the most powerful of all the Eternals of Titan. He is a superhuman Titan mutant born with the ability to synthesise cosmic energy for his own use and has increased his power by bionic amplification, and mystical enhancement by Death herself after she resurrected him.
> <sub>*- [How powerful is Thanos without the Infinity Gauntlet?
>    - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-powerful-is-Thanos-without-the-Infinity-Gauntlet)*</sub>

He is also very intelligent, and his powers are quite *powerful*.

> Thanos has vast scientific knowledge way beyond anything on earth and is a master strategist.
>
> Thanos is immortal and his body is virtually invulnerable to harm. He is immune to most psionic attacks and can release immense blasts of cosmic energy from his hands and eyes and use psychic attacks.
> <sub>*- [How powerful is Thanos without the Infinity Gauntlet?
>    - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-powerful-is-Thanos-without-the-Infinity-Gauntlet)*</sub>

And to answer your question about being able to take on the *Avengers* here is some more info:

> Thanos has vast superhuman strength to a level that he is able take on Thor, Hulk, Beta Ray Bill, The Champion and Tyrant etc.
> [image]
> [image]
> <sub>*-  [How powerful is Thanos without the Infinity Gauntlet?
>    - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-powerful-is-Thanos-without-the-Infinity-Gauntlet)*</sub>

Some people think that Thanos is so dangerous because of how devoted he is.

> The thing that makes Thanos so dangerous however is his nihilistic mind, intelligence, his love of Death and his potential to acquire omnipotence on a regular basis.
> <sub>*-  [How powerful is Thanos without the Infinity Gauntlet?
>    - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-powerful-is-Thanos-without-the-Infinity-Gauntlet)*</sub>

Comment: None of this is from the MCU.

Comment: @Oliver_C im pretty sure Quora didnt write the marvel comics, also why would it have to be MCU the OP is asking about not the films and mcu = marvel *cinematic* universe

Comment: Also, all these powers are *from the comics* i've checked there are no Thanos fanbased powers in that soecific answer on that quora post