# How was this character able to catch Mjolnir and Stormbreaker?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Thanos was able to stop and catch Mjolnir and Stormbreaker mid-air as both Captain America and Thor used/called them **BEFORE** he got the Infinity Stones.

Since this character is clearly not worthy and had no super powers at the time, how were they able to wield Thor's Mjolnir and Stormbreaker, when even the Hulk couldn't do it in *The Avengers*?

Comment: Does he ever wield Mjolnir? I think he just blocks blows and deflects it. Stormbreaker is never shown to be given the same "worthiness" enchantment as Mjolnir, so that's likely not a consideration. Thor does say in *Infinity War* (before actually getting Stormbreaker) that attempting to wield a "Thanos-killing" weapon would destroy any of the Guardians of the Galaxy, but Thanos is considerably more powerful. He was able to touch the Power Stone without any problems, and the *combined* Guardians were only capable of doing that for a small amount of time.

Comment: Yes, Captain America tried to hit him with it (and it's handle) and he caught it and used it to shove/hit Captain America.

Comment: Hmmm... "stopping"  is not the same as "wielding". I remain to be convinced that he wielded Mjolnir.

Comment: He held the hammer, without Captain America's hand having contact with it, **I.E:** he held the hammer alone, without support.

Comment: Hela could do that and Thanos is *way more powerful.

Comment: @Paulie_D So, does that mean that Odin's spell isn't real, because they're both not worthy or does it mean that they're so powerful that Odin's spell has no effect on them?

Comment: As I said, stopping is not wielding. They had enough power to stop Mjolnir in mid air but actually *using* it is entirely different.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hela could do it because her power came from Asgard same as Odin. It was her birthright to use that hammer so she could do whatever she wanted to it.

Comment: @GamerGypps Nope, she could *stop* Mjolnir. at no point does she "wield" Mjolnir.

Comment: @Paulie_D If she stopped it and is holding it in mid air. That is against the enchantment. We have a myriad of evidence that you cannot hold the hammer in mid air. By all rights it should have dropped to the floor pulling her down with it.

Comment: @GamerGypps incorrect. Mjolnir does not just become dead weight as soon as an unworthy person touches it, nor is that how the enchantment works/is phrased. We see the opposite, Spiderman and quicksilver have both attempted to grab the hammer, and (being unworthy) it continued to carry on its intended course with no resistance. The only time we DON'T see that happening is with Helga, and not because she is worthy, or because she's Asgardian, but because she is powerful enough to hold it in place. The hammer is still attempting to fly toward her (as evidenced by the shaking), but she (continued)

Comment: Has the strength to stop it from moving through her. Mjolnir continues to try and push forward while she pushes it back. (speculative: the incredible amounts of force this generates are why Mjolnir begins to crack). She is not wielding it.

Comment: @AAlig I will try and find some but i know there are multiple sources in the comics where beings or people more powerful than Hela have tried to stop the hammer and failed. Stopping and holding the hammer is her enacting force upon the hammer which shouldn't be possible by any means by anyone through pure power or strength. Hela is not that strong in comparison to many others.

Comment: @GamerGypps That's the core issue, is that the MCU(Earth-199999) is inconsistent with regards to the comics. Sometimes the continuities align, but the movies have shown several things that disagree with the main marvel universe (Earth-616), so we can't make assumptions about the MCU based solely on the Comic continuity.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist And the Guardians holding the Stone was mostly Star Lord being half-celestial, and Thor probably didn't know that he was such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>Note: there is significant disagreement about whether Thanos actually *wields* Mjolnir and Stormbreaker. If he doesn't, no further explanation is required. For the purposes of this answer, I'll assume that he does and attempt to explain how this could be possible.</sub>

### The criteria for wielding Mjolnir and Stormbreaker aren't clear.

At the beginning of *Thor (2011)* Odin places this enchantment on Mjolnir:

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power
>   of Thor.

Unfortunately, Odin doesn't provide us with a handy guide of what "worthiness" means to him. Even after Thor becomes worthy at the end of *Thor*, he isn't exactly a paragon of good behavior. He's "heroic" in that he generally tries to do good, but he can also be arrogant<sup>1</sup> and irresponsible<sup>2</sup>. The same descriptors apply to Tony, who can't wield the hammer. Neither can Rhodes, Barton, or Banner.

**Option 1: Thanos is worthy**

In an [excellent answer to a related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99660/73225), A J proposes that the worthiness comes from "being willing to sacrifice [oneself] to protect others." This isn't a airtight explanation<sup>3</sup>. Based on this criteria, Thanos *might actually be worthy*. At the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*, he...

> ...destroys the stones because they are a temptation. Specifically, they are a temptation to the Avengers to destroy the new way of life that he has inflicted on the universe. The effort of doing this nearly kills him.

His logic is twisted, but his intentions are genuine. He believes he is protecting others from a grave threat, and he is willing to sacrifice himself to achieve this protection. It's possible that Mjolnir finds him worthy based on these criteria.

**Option 2: Thanos is powerful**

Thanos has been claimed to be ["the most powerful being in the universe."](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96423/what-makes-thanos-the-most-powerful-being-in-the-universe) It's not clear that this is literally true, but he is a remarkably powerful being able to do things that no one else can. We also know that Odin's magic isn't unbreakable: Hela is able to escape his imprisonment. This is speculation, but there's nothing logically inconsistent about Thanos being able to break or ignore Odin's spell.

<sup>1</sup> "Strongest. Avenger." (Thor, *Thor: Ragnarok*)

<sup>2</sup> "You were supposed to protect us. Asgard was supposed to protect us!" (Eitri, *Avengers: Infinity War*)

<sup>3</sup> Just by being part of the Avengers, Barton and Rhodes risk their lives to help others. It's part of the job description. Futhermore, in *Endgame*, we see that...

> ...Barton is willing to sacrifice his life to get the Soul Stone.

Comment: If the only restriction is "Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor." that doesn't say that unworthy people can't hold the hammer, it just says that unworthy people don't get any special power from holding it. Is it mentioned in the MCU that unworthy people can't hold/wield the hammer?

Comment: @Acccumulation It's shown multiple times that unworthy people can't *lift* the hammer, even though they can hold the handle without any consequences. Physical contact isn't sufficient for the enchantment's definition of "hold" I guess.

Answer (score 26):

Thanos never wields Mjolnir during Endgame.

What happens is Captain America takes a swing with Mjolnir at Thanos, Thanos grabs Captain America's hand (which is holding Mjolnir), and punches Captain America hard enough to knock him down. At this point, Mjolnir flies off to the side out of reach.

At no point does Thanos pick up/hold/carry/use Mjolnir in any way.

Answer (score 16):

**Thanos does not wield Mjolnir, and Stormbreaker has no such requirement**

Thanos does not wield Mjolnir, he blocks it, deflects it, and battles against it but never picks it up and uses it. Therefore worthiness doesn't come into play here.

And Stormbreaker wasn't given any enchantments about worthiness, anyone who is strong enough to wield it can. Not even Mjolnir had any enchantments for worthiness until Thor's first movie when Odin placed it:

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.

Answer (score 0):

Stormbreaker may not have the worthiness requirement, but I myself still think that Thanos was worthy. He genuinely believed that hat he was doing was the right thing to do. He was willing to sacrifice everything he loved (Gamora) and himself (the snap) in order to save half of the universe. He had a plan to save trillions, and he acted on it. He never wanted the stones for power, so after the job was done he destroyed them. These seem like actions that would prove oneself worthy of wielding the power of Thor.

Comment: Killing half of the universe makes one worthy? Well TIL...

Answer (score -1):

There is a mythological nature to this question.

I am happy that some other persons have mentioned Hela, because as mentioned in various comments, Hela stopped Mjolnir in the air; Whether she wielded it or not is immaterial because the writers clearly intended not merely a statement about fandom canon, but about the nature of the hammer and Hela's character.

Namely, they used Mjolnir to demonstrate that Hela's nature and authority both predated and surpassed that of Mjolnir.

This was a statement not about Hela the character, but about the mythological character of death which she represents--that death itself both comes before the power of the worthy hero and is able to dominate him.

This was relevant to the plot because it showed a fundamental change in circumstance like those in many mythological works--Beowulf's battle with the dragon is a great example--this fundamental shift is perceived by the reader or viewer as a tragic but important statement about life itself which rings true to human experience.--The game changes, and even the greatest of mankind succumb to the tragic inevitabilities of human experience.

Likewise, the ability of Thanos to deflect Mjolnir is meant to be a similar indication by the creators; whether the authors' decision here was proper or not to the symbolic essence of Thanos is disputable--But the creators were trying to express that Thanos in himself possesses an authority which is in some way fundamentally primal and predates the authority symbolized by Mjolnir.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, he is worthy, because looking at the science of Mjolnir, you have to be worthy to hold it in way, shape, or form. Remember how in Age of Ultrone, Tony couldn’t lift Mjolnir with his Iron Man hand.

Comment: This contradicts the other answers, which state that Thanos never wielded Mjolnir.