# Why do the Avengers struggle so much against Thanos in "Endgame", when they managed to resist him in "Infinity War" in a supposedly worse situation?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

When Thanos fights the Avengers in *Infinity War*, he always has the Power Stone because that's the first he collected. So he has been fighting with increased power, yet some of the Avengers were able to resist him.

However, in *Endgame​* the same people are fighting him all at once, but can barely resist.

In *Infinity War*, Wanda was destroying the Mind Stone with one hand, while pushing Thanos back with the other hand. And she actually did destroy that Infinity Stone with one hand, so she was using **so much** energy on that mission and wasn't fighting back Thanos in full power. But in *Endgame​*, even using both her hands, she is not strong enough to push him back for more than 3 or 4 seconds.

In *Infinity War*, Captain America, merely a human with strong muscles, can fight Thanos (who had just thrown a moon on Iron Man!) and resist against his punch for some seconds. Meanwhile, Captain Marvel uses her photon blast and superhuman strength to fight him hand-to-hand. Remember that she can carry a spaceship on top of her head all the way from nowhere in space to Earth, and can destroy spaceships just by flying really fast towards them, and doesn't get killed while doing so. Which is faaaaar more that what Steve is capable of, but Thanos throws her like an apple. Or the moon he threw on Tony.

My point is, [I know Thanos is strong, he is a Titan, his skin is unbreakable, highly skilled in combat, etc](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88706/does-thanos-have-any-inherent-superpowers-without-the-infinity-stones). But we've seen in *Infinity War* that some heroes can stand against him while he has the Power Stone. Yet in *Endgame*, they are no match for Stone-free Thanos.

P.S. I did not ask why Thanos is strong. Read the question before marking it as duplicate, please.

Comment: Unknown (powerful AF) enemy at first, then they get to know the enemy, make strategies,battle plans and went onto war with a plan. in the IW movie, what we see is how they just react to the threat. in Endgame, we see they're ready to battle with a plan. simply put

Comment: The Wanda part is not right, after the initial 3-4 seconds, she had Thanos at her mercy. She would have literally shred him apart with her power until Thanos decided to shoot missiles from his space ship

Comment: @KharoBangdo not necessarily. As I see, Thanos didn't try as hard as he should with Wanda. He said he understands what she's going through, I think he deliberately cut some slack for Wanda, because he knew whatever she might do, he can accomplish what he wants.

Comment: @Vishwa i think u r talking about Infinity War. I am talking about Endgame

Comment: @KharoBangdo when it comes to endgame, didn't see it yet mate. and yes I was talking about IW.

Comment: Wanda almost killed Thanos in Endgame if not for his ship firing on the ground

Comment: @Huangism !!Spoilers!! shush :P

Comment: This does not seem to be a duplicate of the linked question, although it could be linked as a related question.

Comment: I think the biggest difference is his attitude. At the beginning of IW, Thanos lays waste to everything in his path to acquire the Power, Space and Reality stones. However, once he sacrifices Gamora to acquire the Soul stone, he shows much more restraint. In the battles on Titan and Earth, he easily could have killed the Avengers at pretty much any moment but chooses not to, which gives them a fighting chance. In Endgame, however, he still very much the ruthless Thanos we saw at the beginning of IW.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanos is strong, even without the stones.

- Thanos was indeed very strong that he managed to beat Hulk in *Infinity War* [without using any Stones](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/92247/33025).
- They barely managed to hurt Thanos in *Infinity War* (all this, for a single drop of blood). But at the end of this battle in *End Game*, Thanos looks pretty much injured.

Some of the key differences between the previous battles with Thanos and this one are,

- Thanos was fighting alone in *Infinity War*, now he is fighting alongside an army (including the Chitauri army). In *Infinity War* all the Avengers were focused only on Thanos but here they need to face his army too.
- The Avengers were surprised here and had to escape a crushing building to fight Thanos, might have been injured in the process.

Now coming to individual heroes,

- Doctor Strange had one of the best one vs one with Thanos. Here he is basically out of the battle preventing that dam breakage.
- Wanda almost crushes/kills Thanos in the battle. He had to rain fire on his own troops to survive. Thanos was no match for her.
- Captain Marvel was holding good against Thanos. He had to take the Power Stone from the Gauntlet and use it against her. Without the Stone, Captain Marvel may have defeated him.
- Thor, Iron Man, Captain America and Hulk may have not even fought in a war for the past five years. They might have been a little out of practice. We can see how Hulk was having difficulty faking aggressiveness in New York.

Comment: Thor was clearly in no shape to fight. <spoiler>He is fat as hell</spoiler>

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but in Endgame he's also a few years younger and wearing armor.